How can I more efficiently appendChild different elements in Javascript?
I'm trying to make a program that requires text with line breaks and superscript elements. I'm trying to figure out how to use up less lines with making the text.
For instance, this is how 2 lines seperated by 2 line breaks are written in my code.
textblock.appendChild(document.createTextNode("this is the first line."))
textblock.appendChild(document.createElement("br"))
textblock.appendChild(document.createElement("br"))
textblock.appendChild(document.createTextNode("this is the second line."))

I'm wondering if I could somehow make this all one line.

Generally speaking, there is nothing more efficient about using less lines of code. Readability / ease of understanding your code should take more of a priority than "use up less lines". In the case of your code example, it's more of a preference for how you want to write it than and improvement by making it "use up less lines".

Referencing the div element in which you want the text directly with ID (document.getElementById()), then with the innerHTML property to write html as string:
document.getElementById("textblock").innerHTML = "This is the first line.<br><br>This is the second line.";

*please, note that this will delete the current content of the element. (IDK if this will be a problem for you)

As I understand you want to replace replace all linebreaks ("\n") with "br". This is the solution below.
const replacedText = text.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>')

You can then use replacedText wherever you want.
